Is it possible to verify data received from the server using the SSL certificate of the server?
I want to verify the authenticity of the data I receive from the server in my nodejs script using the server's SSL certificate.
Main Objective: Ensuring that the node has not returned the tampered data.
I am retrieving the SSL certificate of the server using the following:
let server_certitificate = certificate.raw.toString('base64');

Let me know if you require any more details in the comments.

I'm not fully sure what you want to achieve, but I presume that you want to have some kind of proof of origin for the date you can present to someone else. SSL does not provide this, i.e. it does not sign the application data. It only provides confidentiality and integrity, i.e. protection against sniffing and modification.

Alright! Is there any other way to verify the data received from the server is not tampered in-between?

"verify the data received from the server is not tampered in-between" - that what the use of TLS already implicitly does, i.e. integrity check. So if you create a successful TLS connection, properly validate the certificate (to prevent man in the middle), transfer data and properly close the connection without getting any errors then you can be sure that the data were not tampered with. Even if you get errors during transfer (after certificate validation) you can be sure that any data sent/received so far are not modified.

I understand that. But for my use case: Which is creating a node. I want to verify that the node will always provide the correct and authenticated data, I can verify the certificates as I can get them pass in the response body, but I am not getting how to verify the response data itself.
Also, I understand TLS is already doing that, but I want to implement the same level of layer to verify the data from the node. Is there any way or concept to do this manually?

I interpret this, that you don't want to rely on the existing TLS as the security layer for integrity and confidentiality. Sometimes this makes sense, for example if multiple systems are involved and TLS termination is not done at the same place as the data are generated (for example instead in a CDN). In this case you would need to add another layer on top - like message signatures. These of course would need to be explicitly created by the server, they are not part of TLS. See for example RFC 9421 - HTTP Message Signatures.

Thanks a ton for understanding and for the link. Do have any working example of this where I take some reference from?

I have no code for this, the reference is the standard. But, you can easily find code if you use a search engine and search for implementation rfc9421.
