how to get the encrypted data within the TLS layer in my node script?
I want to build a server that will get data from the API and return it with the SSL certificate, encrypted data in the TLS layer, and the session keys.
From my research,
I found I can get the SSL Certificate using the openssl and verify that using the CA Root certificates with openssl -verify CAfile command.
Also, for the session keys I am capturing them by setting the SSLKEYLOGFILE to a file path.
Now, I want to understand how can I get the encrypted data from the TLS layer.
My Main Objective is to
Verify the data received from a server that the server owner didn't tamper with the data they fetched from the API I provided.

Wireshark can do this. I get the sense that you want to be able to prove something, e.g. you want to prove that you did send some data, or else you want to prove that you didn't send some data. Because TLS "signs" records with symmetric keyed MACs rather than asymmetric algorithms, both sides have the MAC keys so either side can forge TLS records.

I want to use my node script only.
my goal is to achieve this:
server B should be able to verify the data received an API called by serverA is not tampered by serverA

That can't be done using TLS.

ohh okk, but why? also do you have any alternative for this?
Thanks for your time

To reach your objective the API server would need to sign the content, TLS is not sufficient. This signature could then be verified by anybody receiving the signed content, no matter if there was some TLS terminating system in between or not. For more on this check the comments on your last question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78334798/is-it-possible-to-verify-data-received-from-the-server-using-the-ssl-certificate
